# How to forbid replacing process.env variables during compilation in webpack?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, aws-lambda, webpack-4

**Story**

I'm developing the AWS Lambda functions and compile the code using `webpack`.

I've read some of the articles and it seems that the `process.env` variables are auto replaced during compilation. Although it's cool I want to forbid this behaviour.

**Why?**

Because I'm passing environment variables using AWS Lambda dashboard.

**Webpack configuration**

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.ts'),
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          experimentalWatchApi: true,
        },
      }],
    }]
  },
  plugins: [],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
}
```

**Question**

Is it possible to forbid the behaviour of replacing the `process.env` variables during `webpack` compilation? 
If yes please help me to achieve this effect.

Comment: I realize this doesn't help you (and that I'm a year late), but adding `target: 'node'` to my config fixed this for me, so it is even odder that yours is not working.

Comment: On prod mode, it does not work for me

Comment: `optimization.nodeEnv` set to `false` should work

Comment: In my case, I'm building a react image in docker with webpack, and replacing environment variables in the final image with sed when deploying with kubernetes in a given environment (gives a 20sec deploy time). We've had a lot of trouble because of process.env optimizations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mode` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode) in Webpack configuration enables the replacement of `process.env.NODE_ENV`:

> development
>
> Sets process.env.NODE_ENV on DefinePlugin to value development.
> Enables NamedChunksPlugin and NamedModulesPlugin.
>
> production
>
> Sets process.env.NODE_ENV on DefinePlugin to value production. Enables
> FlagDependencyUsagePlugin, FlagIncludedChunksPlugin,
> ModuleConcatenationPlugin, NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin,
> OccurrenceOrderPlugin, SideEffectsFlagPlugin and TerserPlugin.
>
> none
>
> Opts out of any default optimization options

So does [`webpack -p` CLI option](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#cli-alternatives).

In case, the effect of `DefinePlugin` on `process.env.NODE_ENV` is not desirable, listed plugins should be applied without `DefinePlugin`, as the documentation shows for [`production`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/#mode-production) and [`development`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/#mode-development) modes.

For the configuration with no environment variables except `NODE_ENV`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64157146/3731501) may be suitable.

**This is applicable to Webpack 4 with custom configuration similar to the one provided in the question. This may be different for other Webpack versions or the tools that provide their own Webpack configuration like Vue CLI and Create React App.**

Comment: I don't understand why you are mentioning only `process.env.NODE_ENV` when the OP asked something regarding the replacement of all process.env.

Furthermore, we don't want to disable all optimizations, but only the one that would replace `process.env.X` by their actual value. So setting NODE_ENV to development.

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris Because it's specifically the effect of DefinePlugin on process.env.NODE_ENV that has been documented at the time of posting (Webpack 4, not 5), and the answer quotes the relevant part. It does not apply to all environment variables, so this generalization is not applicable, unless Webpack config makes it work in some other way. If it's the case then DefinePlugin config needs to be fixed in some way that depends on a setup. What I see is that the answer doesn't fit your case, which differs from the OP. Thanks for the argumented downvote though.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to remove my downvote given your feedback but unfortunately SO does not let me unless the post is edited ^^" Maybe you can just mention your answer applies to webpack 4 ?

Comment: No problems, I edited for clarity.

Comment: This is not desired, I wish to not replace it at all for Node env

Answer (score 8):

Set `optimization.nodeEnv` to `false`

From:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationnodeenv

> optimization.nodeEnv
>
> boolean = false string
>
> Tells webpack to set process.env.NODE_ENV to a given string value. optimization.nodeEnv > uses DefinePlugin unless set to false. optimization.nodeEnv defaults to mode if set, > else falls back to 'production'.

Answer (score 4):

While setting `optimization.nodeEnv` to `false` works for the `NODE_ENV` variable, it doesn't work for *all* environment variables, and it doesn't prevent `process.env` from being replaced in the compiled code.

I'm working with Webpack on the backend, so having access during *runtime* is important.

Since there doesn't seem to be an official way of preserving `process.env` in the compiled code, I found this workaround, which worked for me.

I had to define a new global variable, which I called `ENVIRONMENT`, that will be replaced with `process.env` during compilation.

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  ENVIRONMENT: 'process.env',
}),
```

In my code, I would then access it like a regular object:

```js
ENVIRONMENT.DATABASE_URL
```

The above compiles to `process.env.DATABASE_URL`.

Comment: How do you declare "ENVIRONMENT" as a globally available variable in typescript ?

Comment: You can declare the variable by putting the following in a `*.d.ts`file: `declare const ENVIRONMENT: YourInterface;`

Answer (score 2):

I bumped on the same issue with webpack replacing process.env varibles at build time. For a SSR application this is not the wanted behavior.

As a workaround I managed to fool webpack by using something like this in my code:

`process['e' + 'nv'].MY_VARIABLE`

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work. Still replace the variables... kind of weird.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to avoid this behavior by adding the following entry into my define plugin to have it skip replacing process.env.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': 'process.env',
        }),
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to avoid this behavior in my vue.config.js by adding:

```
const Config = require('webpack-chain');
const config = new Config();
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete("define")
  },
  configureWebpack: {
  ...,
  },
  .....
}
```