# Read process.env at runtime webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, nodes, webpack-4

I'm building my function with webpack that get deployed to `AWS lambda`.
I currently have to specify the environment variable at compile time for them to be available as per [webpack doc](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/).

This is awesome for web deployment, but for **node** I might want to change the values passed at build, by changing the env file i'm sourcing from. For example `.env.staging` or `.env.production` without having to rebuild the application or directly on my lambda environment.

How can I achieve this if possible? I'm using `webpack4`

Comment: If your target is `node` then you can access `process.env` during runtime. There is no need to "inject" environment variables with webpack when you are bundling a node app.

Comment: Yes I can, but by that time it has already been processed by `webpack` and its value is `undefined`

Comment: I currently have to define the variables to be available at compile time https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/

Comment: This is good for a web target, but for a node application, I would want to have a build  I could pass its `enviroment` values to at runtime, not have `webpack` replace all instance of `process.env.*` for me

Comment: Having this same problem.  Was there any resolution?

Comment: @andrsnn I ended up having to rebuild when deploying to a different environment.
This answer tries to explain more about the mode and how they affect the final output, but I'm yet to try it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/53801891/4296706
Relevant webpack link: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode

Comment: You can give a try at this: https://medium.com/@albertfrimpong/access-runtime-environment-variable-in-a-webpack-app-248448246f24